# Processor Throttling, Speeds and Battery life

Tags: windows, cpu, battery, battery-life, cpu-speed

Does throttling the CPU down give you more battery life? Does i3 give you more battery life over an i7? Just I've not had the options to really test this theory as it requires having the same laptops just different CPUS.

Answer (score 1):

> Does throttling the CPU down give you more battery life?

Yes. Throttling the CPU would result in less of it's processing power being utilized, which would result in it requiring less energy and generate less heat.

> Does i3 give you more battery life over an i7?

It depends on which i3 and i7 you are comparing, there are many versions of each. You could simply look at the wattage rating for the processors you are comparing and the one that is higher would consume more power. No testing necessary.

Comment: Not *completely* accurate. CPUs can be undervolted. The TDW "wattage" is more accurate for determining consumption under full load. Undervolting is common when the CPU is throttled down.

Comment: @NathanC You are correct, I updated my answer.